# setFocusPainted used for JButtons

Tags: java, button, user-interface

I am a Begginer in Java. I am trying to create a small GUI that is going to resize and allign left,right a given image. Could you please explain or redirect me to an article-doc about the setfocuspainted method ??

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but here's a link to the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted(boolean)

Comment: I don't know what "allign left,right a given image" means, but try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=setfocuspainted+java) out.

Answer (score 1):

The `setFocusPainted` method can be used to set wether or not there is a blue focus ring around the component. For example: `randomButton.setFocusPainted(true);` will give `randomButton` a focus ring and `randomButton.setFocusPainted(false);` will remove the focus ring.